# instalar firefox via docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

via `docker-compose` estoy tratando de instalar firefox dentro del contenidor con este extracto como un `.dockerfile`

```
# See https://codeship.com/documentation/docker/browser-testing/
FROM python:3.6.5

# We need wget to set up the PPA and xvfb to have a virtual screen and unzip to install the Chromedriver
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install firefox

ADD ./app ./app
ADD ./.env ./.env

# COPY POETRY DEPENDENCIES FILES
ADD ./requirements.txt ./app/requirements.txt

# INSTALLING DEPENDENCIES
RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip &&  \
    python -m pip install -r ./app/requirements.txt

# FIX LOGS IN DOCKER CONTAINER
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
```

Sin embargo me arroja un error al momento de generar mi imagen:

```
E: Package 'firefox' has no installation candidate
ERROR: Service 'xxx' failed to build : The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update &&     apt-get install firefox /var/lib/apt/lists/*' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

¿Cúal seria el comando correcto que debo agregar en la seccion de RUN antes de apt-get install firefox?. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Vi que era complicado levantar Firefox, más bien opté por chrome y mi `.dockerfile` quedó así:

```
# See https://codeship.com/documentation/docker/browser-testing/
FROM python:3.6.5

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y gnupg wget curl unzip --no-install-recommends && \
    wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - && \
    echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list && \
    apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable && \
    google-chrome-stable -version
    
ADD ./app ./app
ADD ./.env ./.env

# COPY POETRY DEPENDENCIES FILES
ADD ./requirements.txt ./app/requirements.txt

# INSTALLING DEPENDENCIES
RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip &&  \
    python -m pip install -r ./app/requirements.txt

# FIX LOGS IN DOCKER CONTAINER
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
```